# Java division for double and float without E

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I'm doing some large number divisions (long/long to double, and int/int to float).. But I bump, to a problem when the results include the "E". I know we can use NumberFormat to format when displaying, but that's not what I. Just want the result of the divisions to not involve the "E", i.e. just round it up to the closest float/double that fits in the space.

Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Could you edit your question with: the code you have to print out this  data (just the relevant part), the ouput you're getting, and the ouput you would want?

Comment: I'm confused: How does what you're trying to do not involve number formatting? Why the restriction not to use NumberFormat?

Comment: cause i dont want the number stored in the memory to be different from what is represented. If i am to round the number to display to the user, that means the number stored in the memory should be too. Otherwise it's a problem on my side..

Comment: But you're confusing String representation of a number with the number itself. There's no way a floating point number will exactly equal it's String representation. Your goal is unrealistic and a bit naïve. Please read up on digital representations of floating point numbers to better understand this.

Comment: double and float always use an exponential, its why its called `floating point` i.e. the decimal point floats.  You can avoid printing it, but its always there.

Answer (score 7):

The internal representation of floating point number does not have a switch for E presence or not (check IEEE-754). So your float/double number is just number (not a number with E or without it).

The only place where you get E is when you print this value out. And while Java uses number formater for printing, so I don't see a point why you don't want to use it here.

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.#####").format(doubleValue));
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for a solution to print it out. But your input gave me more understanding how these numbers work in java.. thanks, man..

Answer (score 0):

The general problem that double and float in binary format. It not always possible to convert decimal fraction to binary fraction. For example 0.2 decmal fraction have infinitely many digits in binary (double) format. So whe converted from bynary format to decimal string, it result something like "0.2000000001" what displayed with E. To solve this problem you can use BigDecimal class what contains number in decimal format, so no E problem - it can easy rounded to any decimal point by setScale method. Or you can sore double as is, an write it to output by String.format("My value are: %.3f", value) - i recommend this way.

If you just want round you value to decimal point you can use:

```
new BigDecimal(val).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).doubleValue()
```

But there no any garanty what this core return double with fine fraction numbers.