# Java amount format

Tags: java

I am having 156 amounts and when I am summing up to get the total amount the amount format is like `323E43.32` which I dont want but I want it in 344234.45 format. I got the individual amount in string and before performing any operation I have typcasted it to double value.

Is there a way to format a amount from `323E43.32` to `344234.45` in java?

Code Snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numrows; i++)
{
    double temp=Double.parseDouble(orders.getString("AMOUNT"));
    totalAmount=totalAmount+temp;
    bean.setTotalAmount(totalAmount);
}
```

Comment: 156 amounts, is that the number of rows you need to sum up?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on how you are printing the value. Is this done in JSF/JSP or what?

Comment: also, how can 323E43.32 ever be converted to 344234.45?

Comment: @JoelWestberg: i am printing the amount in text file where the individual amounts are in "373974.22" format but the total amount is in "1.8687660340800426E9=" format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this thread solve your problem?

[Java division for double and float without E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054836/java-division-for-double-and-float-without-e)

with this code:

```
  System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("#.#####").format(doubleValue));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you take a look at [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
    Double price2 = Double.parseDouble(decim.format(price));
    System.out.println(price2); // it will print it in the default format
```

If you want to print the formatted representation, print using the format:

```
    String s = formatter.format(price);
    System.out.println("s is '"+s+"'");
```

Also take a look at [How to format decimal numbers?](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-format-decimal-number-in-java.html)